# Get child class name in parent method

Tags: php, oop

I have a function in the parent class and I extend the parent class now I want to get the child class name in parent function and perform some action.

Here is code example which I'm trying but this is not working for me.

**Parent Class (Foo)**

```
 class Foo {
     function method(){
        $childeClass = self::class;
        // code
     }
 }
```

**Child class (Bar)**

```
class Bar extends Foo{}
```

How can I get child class name **Bar** in the parent method? `self::class` is not returning the child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using **Late Static Binding**

> late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call"

You can not achieve it by using `self::class` instead of this use `static::class`

```
 class Foo {
     function method(){
        $childeClass = static::class;
        // code
     }
 }
```

For more information read [Late Static Binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)